# How to append a div with two different divs using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hello recently I am using sweet pages pagination for my website. I want to display the pagination controll on top and bottom of the pages. How can I do that?

Now the codes are like this

```
var controls = $('.swControls').detach();

controls.appendTo('#sliderPag');

controls.clone().appendTo('#main2');
```

This is working

But the bottom links are not working.. I cant understand why its not working. any body knows the solution please help me..

Comment: Use live events instead of bind, and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var controls = $('.swControls').detach();
controls.appendTo('#sliderPag');
controls.clone(true).appendTo('#main2');
```

Comment: Hello sir its working but the top links are not active :( please check this link.. http://bannerdesign.co/portfolio.php

Comment: I updated the code (notice the clone(true)), this way it will copy the attached event handlers as well.

Comment: It's because the plugin your using is not able to handle multiple control bars. I converted the click event into a live event - http://k3rmit.org/nopaste/753 - I believe the cloned event handler weren't working because of the missing context variables.